# Appending values in a list and then sending as a JSON object

Tags: json, scala

```
    var jsonElements = List[String]()
    val params = Map("host"->host)
    for((key,value)<-mapSql){
      val map = Map("metric"->key,"timestamp"->new Date().getTime,"value"->value,"tags"->params)
       jsonElements=JsonUtility.toJSONString(map) :: jsonElements

    }


    val entity = new StringEntity(JsonUtility.toJSONString(jsonElements))
    println("json elements final list is "+jsonElements)
    println("json elements final JSON Obj is "+JsonUtility.toJSONString(jsonElements))
    entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"))
    val postRequest: HttpPost = new HttpPost(putURL)
    postRequest.setEntity(entity)
    val postResponse: CloseableHttpResponse = httpclient.execute(postRequest)
```

I basically need to add values to a list and then send them together in a JSON Array.
However this is introducing unnecessary escape characters "/" in the output which is rendering the post request useless and I am getting an error to the API hit. the following is the response :

```
json elements final list is List({"metric":"replicationLag","timestamp":1410179907871,"value":0.0,"tags":{"host":"tg-em-db01.nm.xxxx.com"}}, {"metric":"status","timestamp":1410179907824,"value":1,"tags":{"host":"tg-em-db01.nm.xxxxx.com"}})
json elements final JSON Obj is ["{\"metric\":\"replicationLag\",\"timestamp\":1410179907871,\"value\":0.0,\"tags\":{\"host\":\"tg-em-db01.nm.xxxx.com\"}}","{\"metric\":\"status\",\"timestamp\":1410179907824,\"value\":1,\"tags\":{\"host\":\"tg-em-db01.nm.xxxxx.com\"}}"]
```

I can replace and remove all the escape characters by the replaceAll function but I do not want to do that. is there a better way to append objects to an already existing JSON object and then change it to an array ( which i can easily do by new JsonArray(List(JsonObj)) ) so that i dont get any escape characters anywhere.

Something like this :

```
    val params = Map("host"->host)
    var map = Map[String,Any]()
    for((key,value)<-mapSql){
      map ++= Map("metric"->key,"timestamp"->new Date().getTime,"value"->value,"tags"->params)
    }

    val entity = new StringEntity(JsonUtility.toJSONString(List(map)))
    println("json elements final list is "+map)
    println("json elements final JSON Obj is "+JsonUtility.toJSONString(List(map)))
```

is giving me this as an ouput :

```
json elements final list is Map(metric -> replicationLag, timestamp -> 1410180939983, value -> 0.0, tags -> Map(host -> tg-em-db01.nm.xxxx.com))
json elements final JSON Obj is [{"metric":"replicationLag","timestamp":1410180939983,"value":0.0,"tags":{"host":"tg-em-db01.nm.xxxxx.com"}}]
```

But I need something like this :

```
[ {"metric":blah blah} , {"metric":blah blah} ]
```

Is there a way to append to maps such that the same key values are not clubbed ?

Thanks in advancE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var jsonElements = List[Map[String, Any]]()
    val params = Map("host" -> host)
    for ((key, value) <- mapSql) {
      val map = Map("metric" -> key, "timestamp" -> new Date().getTime, "value" -> value, "tags" -> params)
      jsonElements = map :: jsonElements
}
val entity = new StringEntity(JsonUtility.toJSONString(jsonElements))
entity.setContentType(new BasicHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"))
val postRequest: HttpPost = new HttpPost(putURL)
postRequest.setEntity(entity)
val postResponse: CloseableHttpResponse = httpclient.execute(postRequest)

object JsonUtility {

 def toJSONString(obj:Any):String = {
    compact(JsonAST.render(decompose(obj)))
  }
}
```